# Bit-tweaking in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Just curious. I did a program in C, with quite an amount of bitwise operations for a variable which defines access controls for a page. I wanna be able to do the same in Javascript only. How can i accomplish this ordeal?

Any help in bit-tweaking in Javascript will help. Remember no costly functions allowed.

Comment: May I recommend you don't write C in JavaScript. Try to use JavaScript like a functional dynamic language instead.

Comment: I guess i wasn't clear. C coding was used for the server side development. Javascript for the client side. I just wanted to avoid overloading the server. Hence my question.

Comment: I meant do write JavaScript code in a C-style. It can be easy to write procedural style code in javascript due to the syntax similarities but it just becomes a mess. There really shouldn't be much reason to use bit manipulation in JavaScript apart from classics such as hashing functions.

Comment: Clearly I meant _don't_ write JavaScript code in C-style.

Comment: Ahh, Alright. I'll try my best to avoid it. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has the usual assortment of bitwise operators, `|`, `&`, `~`, etc.; details in [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

The following sections will be particularly useful:

- Section 11.4.8: Bitwise NOT (`~`)
- Section 11.7: Bitwise Shift Operators (`<<` and `>>`)
- Section 11.10: Binary Bitwise Operators (`|` and `&`)

Note that JavaScript's numbers are all floating point (see Section 8.5, *The Number Type*, in [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)), but the bitwise operations are defined in terms of integers. So for instance, the definition of the bitwise NOT operator:

> **11.4.8 Bitwise NOT Operator ( `~` )**
>   
> The production `UnaryExpression : ~ UnaryExpression` is evaluated as follows:
>   
> 1. Let `expr` be the result of evaluating `UnaryExpression`.
>   
> 2. Let `oldValue` be `ToInt32(GetValue(expr))`.
>   
> 3. Return the result of applying bitwise complement to `oldValue`. The result is a signed 32-bit integer.

Any decent implementation will be able to handle these efficiently, avoiding unnecessary conversions from `Number` to internal integer and back.

Comment: Thank you. Quite comprehensive.

Comment: And for even more details see  http://bateru.com/news/2011/03/javascript-binary-operations-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has bitwise operators like other languages. Bitwise operators are, by definition, efficient. You should be able to replicate all the bitwise operations performed in your C program in JS as well.

http://www.eecs.umich.edu/~bartlett/jsops.html